# How do I use "call PutDec" in Assembly Language? It should print out the ax register but for some reason it gives me nothing

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, cpu-registers

I have been practicing a problem in my Assembly class and I can't figure out why, after I compile and run my program, the output is garbage, being illegible characters.
The equation for the problems is A = B * 3 +6 / (X + D)
where B == 10, X == 4, D == 2

```
 INCLUDE PCMAC.inc
   .model     small
   .586
   .stack  100h
   .data
   B    dw 0
   X    dw 0
   D    dw 0
   A    dw 0

   X_Prompt DW 'X',$
   B_Prompt DW 'Y',$
   D_Prompt DW 'D',$
 ;  Message DB      A,$

       .CODE
       EXTRN getDec: Near, putDec: Near
Box PROC
       _Begin
       _PutStr B_Prompt
       call getDec
       mov    B, ax
       mov    ax, 3
       mul B  ; B*3 (10 *3) portion of the equation. stored in dx
       mov B, dx

       _PutStr X_Prompt
       call getDec
       mov  X, ax
       _PutStr D_Prompt
       call getDec
       add X, ax
       mov ax, X
       div B
       call PutDec
```

I also tried using _PutStr Message and displaying A. But this didn't work either so I tried to use PutDec. I'm not sure whats wrong with it.

```
       _Exit 0
       Box ENDP
       END Box
```

Comment: Assembly language doesn't have any standard functions.  Is `PutDec` something provided by your teacher or another library you are using?  You had better ask them how it's meant to be used.

Comment: A hint, by the way: pay attention to the exact behavior of the `div` instruction, particularly the role of the `dx` register.

Comment: `putDec` should never produce "illegible characters" but of course we don't know how it's implemented.

Comment: Also, your prompts should almost certainly be `DB` instead of `DW` as a string is a sequence of bytes, not words.

Comment: I got the code to print out numbers but its almost as if my B value doesn't exist at all. Am I storing it in the wrong register?

Comment: The `mul` puts the low half of the result into `ax` not `dx` (which is the top half). Also in the `div B` instruction `B` is the divisor and you don't even mention the `6` in the code.

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).